# ArcPy spatial join stops without error

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

I am trying to run a spatial join on ArcPy. The files are quite large, and I am running the code in Idle. The code seems to "stop" without producing an error.

My code is as follows:

```
a = shapefile1.shp
b = Default.gdb\\shapefile2
y = shapefile2.shp
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(a, b, y, "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY", "KEEP_ALL")
print("finished join 1")
```

The code stops without printing "finished join 1". However it does not produce an error. I am not sure if it finishes the join either, it produces a large file, but I have no way of checking if it is complete.

Comment: What happens when you run the same parameter values through the Spatial Join tool dialog?

Comment: `b`is set to an invalid path. Shapefiles ***cannot*** exist in a file geodatabase.

Comment: Have you defined a workspace with `arcpy.env.workspace`?

Comment: Maybe the output exceed the shapefile 2gb limit. Try outputting as a feature class in a file geodatabase (`b = r"C:\somefolder\Default.gdb\out_spatial_join"`)

Comment: @BERA wow, it was going over 2GB. let me try this

Comment: @Vince yeah sorry, the .shp was not meant to be there